# PassportJS, ExpressJS, NodeJS, Creating API w/ Authentication

Tags: json, node.js, express, passport.js

Im using PassportJS in ExpressJS application:

In `app.js`, I have route for admin-only and `requiresAdmin` function:

```
var requiresAdmin = function() {
    return [
        ensureLoggedIn('/login'),
        function(req, res, next) {
            if (req.user && req.user.admin === true){
                next();
            }else{
                res.send(401, 'Unauthorized');
            }
        }
    ];
};

app.all('/admin/*', requiresAdmin());
```

I created another route that will return JSON object. Also can be accessed by admin.

```
app.all('/api/admin/*', requiresAdmin());
```

If users are not logged in or non-admin, how to return JSON using the above approach? Thanks

Comment: Why not using the content negotiation feature of express? see this link: [res.format](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Express.js content negotiation feature by just replacing your res.send with the following:

```
res.format({
  'text/plain': function(){
    res.send(401, 'Unauthorized');
  },

  'application/json': function(){
    res.send(401, { message: 'Unauthorized' });
  }
});
```

More info here: http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.format

Don't forget to replace your `res.send` within `ensureLoggedIn`, and remember that you will might need to enforce your clients to send the proper `accept` header within their http requests.

Comment: Im using module https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-ensure-login, where to replace `res.send`?

Comment: Sorry I thought it was a function you wrote your self. Have a look at this issue: https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-ensure-login/pull/3 - Not sure how you will have to deal with this scenario as you are using a third party library.